# How can I create a filmstrip with a timer from video or trace file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, video

I am creating performance audits using `puppeteer`.
The puppeteer scripts produce 4 files, two trace files for before and after, and two video mp4 files for before and after.

Now with those files what I would like to do is create something like this:

[image: Filmstrip with timer]

There is no need for this to run on a browser if that makes any difference and should be able to run on a server.

Comment: _"I would like to create something like this"_ You should explain better your expected final result: For example **(1)** Are you expecting to output an image (jpg/png) of a filmstrip? Or you actually expect to have HTML of an interactive timeline in filmstrip format? **(2)** Where are you stuck in your code? You can use `<canvas>` for creating image of a filmstrip... or use dynamic HTML for interactive filmstrip, where the HTML creates `<div>`, `<text>` and `<canvas>` tags for when you need text or image added into it (..."it" being the `<div>`, which is your container of timeline contents)

Comment: Oh my apologies, I thought it was explained by the server comment. The output is suppose to be an image, jpeg/png

Comment: Ok. I thought you meant the server generates the timeline... But it has to generate something visual, right? (like it outputs an image of a filmstrip)... **PS:** No worries I see **your edit**. You want an image.

Comment: Yes it generates a png/jpeg. Moreover, no browser, the file gets stored on a directory and does no get used in a web app.  No HTML wanted or needed. The server takes two videos and generates the same as the image I posted as a png.

Comment: Well I'm an image-processing code guy, so I'll step away now. I guess you're looking for server-based tools/scripts that can generate the image? Maybe also ask at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or as last resort try asking at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). You can use your S.O account to instantly join those sites. PS: Tools to try could be FFmpeg or ImageMagick..